# Considering we already have `setOrigin`, what is "Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center" used for?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm confused about the use case of `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center`, the following code is adapted from [an official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/display/align/in-top-left)

```js
class Example extends Phaser.Scene
{
  constructor ()
  {
    super();
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/master/public/assets/';
    this.load.image('pic', 'pics/barbarian-loading.png');
  }
  create ()
  {
    const pic = this.add.image(400, 300, 'pic');
    //Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(pic, this.add.zone(400, 300, 800, 600));
  }
}
var config = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
backgroundColor: '#666', //0xf3f3f3
  scene: [Example]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

where I've commented this line out

```
//Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(pic, this.add.zone(400, 300, 800, 600));
```

No matter if I use this line, I get the exactly same result, a centered image.

Considering we already have `setOrigin`, what is "Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center" used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Phaser.Display.Align` is used for positioning objects relative to another objects. `setOrigin` is just used to define from where the coordinats of the object should be calculated.

In this example you can see how you can position an object relative to another (with `Phaser.Display.Align`), but ***without knowing/setting the coordinates*** for it.

> It is good/used for, positioning to images on top/next of eachother like clothes, guns, *text on items*, ...

On each click, the green rectangle will be repositioned, with `Phaser.Display.Align`.
*(I'm using both `Phaser.Display.Align.In` and `Phaser.Display.Align.To` to illustrate the difference )*.

```js
function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click red Cube', '#ffffff')
    rect1 = this.add.rectangle(200, 100, 50, 50, 0xff0000);
    rect2 = this.add.rectangle(-50, -50, 30, 30, 0x00ff00);
    
    Phaser.Display.Align.To.TopCenter(rect2, rect1);
    
    rect1.setInteractive();
    rect1.on('pointerdown', alignObject)
    
  }
  
 function alignObject(){
    switch(alignObjPoistion){
      case 0:
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.TopCenter(rect2, rect1);
        break;
      case 1:
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(rect2, rect1);
        break;
      case 2:
        Phaser.Display.Align.In.BottomCenter(rect2, rect1);
        break;
      case 3:
        Phaser.Display.Align.To.BottomCenter(rect2, rect1);
        break;
      case 4:
        Phaser.Display.Align.To.TopCenter(rect2, rect1);

        alignObjPoistion = -1;
    }
    alignObjPoistion++;
 }
 
var alignObjPoistion = 0;
var rect1; 
var rect2; 

var config = {
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  scene: { create }
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Assume `pic` in the official example acts a similar function to `rect2` in yours, then `this.add.zone(400, 300, 800, 600)` appears to be the counterpart of `rect1`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct